# SwiftUI - How to use Result in Swift

Tags: swiftui

If I use this code, work fine.

```
import Foundation

enum NetworkError: Error {
    case badURL }

func fetchUnreadCount(from urlString: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Int, NetworkError>) -> Void)  {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completionHandler(.failure(.badURL))
        return
    }
    // complicated networking code here
    print("Fetching \(url.absoluteString)...")
    completionHandler(.success(5)) }




fetchUnreadCount(from: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let count):
        print("\(count) unread messages.")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } }
```

If I use the same code with SwiftUI, don't work (see screen shot belove)

[image]

How do I go about eliminating errors?

Comment: `body` have to return a View, so just add `return EmptyView()` or whatever view you wanna display after `fetchUnreadCount`

Comment: Could you give me an example from the code above?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`body` have to return a View, so just add `return EmptyView()` or whatever view you wanna display after `fetchUnreadCount`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        fetchUnreadCount(from: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com") { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let count):
                print("\(count) unread messages.")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } }

        return EmptyView()

    }
}
```

Anyways, you should not do such thing as fetching data in a View, this work should be done in the model